# Sort List according to the value of dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

i have a list of dictionary like:

```
[{'apr': 567.82,
  'aug': 567.82,
  'dec': 0.0,
  'feb': 0.0,
  'jan': 0.0,
  'jul': 567.82,
  'jun': 567.82,
  'mar': 0.0,
  'may': 567.82,
  'nov': 0.0,
  'oct': 567.82,
  'sep': 567.82,
  'tenantname': 7,
  'unitname': 4},
 {'apr': 0.0,
  'aug': 0.0,
  'dec': 567.82,
  'feb': 0.0,
  'jan': 0.0,
  'jul': 0.0,
  'jun': 0.0,
  'mar': 0.0,
  'may': 0.0,
  'nov': 567.82,
  'oct': 0.0,
  'sep': 0.0,
  'tenantname': 2,
  'unitname': 4},
 {'apr': 0.0,
  'aug': 0.0,
  'dec': 0.0,
  'feb': 567.82,
  'jan': 567.85,
  'jul': 0.0,
  'jun': 0.0,
  'mar': 567.82,
  'may': 0.0,
  'nov': 0.0,
  'oct': 0.0,
  'sep': 0.0,
  'tenantname': 1,
  'unitname': 4}]
```

I want to sort the list according to value of dict, such that

- dict with value for the month 'jan','feb','mar' will come first
- dict with value for the month 'apr','may' , .... will come second
- dict with value for the month 'nov','dec' will come last

Comment: Perhaps making any sort of attempt at this and then asking for help would be more constructive

Comment: Please use pprint to print the dictionary, this is totally unreadable. Substitution of values like 567.82000000000005 would also be a good idea. Also, I don't quite get what are you trying to achieve. Try to clarify your problem.

Comment: @BeRecursive: +1 for pun

Comment: @Matt I was worried no-one would get it without it being in italics - stupid comment formatting

Comment: *Italics* don't work in *comments*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your dictionary as

`urdict=[{'mar': 0.0, 'sep': 567.82000000000005, 'may': 567.82000000000005, 'jun': 567.82000000000005, 'jul': 567.82000000000005, 'nov': 0.0, 'feb': 0.0, 'aug': 567.82000000000005,'jan': 0.0, 'apr': 567.82000000000005, 'dec': 0.0, 'oct': 567.82000000000005}, {'mar': 0.0, 'sep': 0.0, 'may': 0.0, 'jun': 0.0, 'jul': 0.0,  'nov': 567.82000000000005, 'feb': 0.0, 'aug': 0.0, 'jan': 0.0, 'apr': 0.0, 'dec': 567.82000000000005, 'oct': 0.0}, {'mar': 567.82000000000005, 'sep': 0.0, 'may': 0.0, 'jun': 0.0, 'jul': 0.0, 'nov': 0.0, 'feb': 567.82000000000005, 'aug': 0.0, 'jan': 567.82000000000005, 'apr': 0.0, 'dec': 0.0, 'oct': 0.0}]`

Create a Dictionary of Months

```
month={'jan':0,'feb':1,'mar':2,'apr':3,'may':4,'jun':5,'jul':6,'aug':7,'sep':8,'oct':9,'nov':10,'dec':11}
```

Create an empty Dictionary List to store your final result

```
ursorteddicts=[]
```

Then use the `month dictionary as a cross reference while sorting your dictionary. The Final result should be stored in an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to preserve the order. Note before sorting you need to convert the dictionary to list of (key,value) tuples

```
for d in urdict:
    ursorteddicts.append(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems()),key=lambda x:month[x[0]])))
```